# Help with "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License"

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, derivative-work, publishing

I have a dataset to be used for Data Science research. This dataset (will be referenced henceforth as the "Original Dataset"), is licensed (to the best of my knowledge) under [CCA-NC-ND](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-reuse-an-excerpt-of-a-larger-work-that-is-licensed-with-the-noderivs-restriction).

I have worked towards creating a specialized **subset** where the said subset-partition (henceforth "New Dataset") was created solely from the *Original Dataset* using some algorithmic procedures. The *New Dataset* aims at standardizing certain aspects while adding to the richness of the *Original Dataset*'s information content.

My question is this: am I legally allowed to publish the *New Dataset*?

Comment: Could you indicate where you're located? Some jurisdictions recognize **database rights**. If such rights are relevant, then subsetting the database would likely be a derivative work within the meaning of this license: you must consider both the licenses of the database bas a whole, and the individual entries in the database.

Comment: @amon, the [CC-NC-ND license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/legalcode.txt) covers database rights as well as copyright (see definition "j" and section 4).